# Show that TQBF $\notin$ SPACE$((\log{n})^4)$?

Tags: complexity-theory

How do I show that TQBF $\notin$ SPACE$((\log{n})^4)$?  I know that TQBF is PSPACE complete, but is this the right approach?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Space Hierarchy Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem)? (Assuming that you're not for some reason restricted from using it.

Comment: I know the Space Hierarchy Theorem.  I don't "see" how it applies to the problem though.

Comment: Take a look at Corollary 5 on the Wikipedia page, does that get you closer?

Comment: How would I show that TQBF is one of these problems?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: TQBF is PSPACE-complete, so it "requires" polynomial space. If there were an algorithm to solve TQBF using space $O(\log^4 n)$, you could use it to solve *all* problems in PSPACE using surprisingly small space. So surprising, in fact, that the space hierarchy theorem says it can't be.

Answer (score 2):

Another hint: As $TQBF$ is PSPACE-complete, for every problem $L$ in PSPACE, there exists a reduction $f$ such that for every instance $x$ of $L$ we can construct an instance $f(x)$ of $TQBF$ in time $O(n^{d})$ for some $d\in\mathbb{N}$ (note that $d$ depends on $f$, so it's unbounded, it can be different for every $f$).

Then there's two questions:

1. If $|x| = n$, what can $|f(x)|$ be at most?
2. Then how much space could you solve $x$ in if you could solve $f(x)$ with at most $O(\log^{4}n)$?

Comment: For part 1, so if $|x|=n$, then $|f(x)|$ is at most $O(n^d)$, since $f$ runs for $O(n^d)$ steps, and adds something for each step. For part 2, you can solve $x$ in $O(n^{1/d}\log^4{n})$ space, right?

Comment: Almost, you're definitely nearly there, your arithmetic is a bit wrong at the end though: $(\log(n^{d}))^{4} =\ldots$.

Comment: you can solve $x$ in $(\log{n^d})^4 = d^4 \log^4{n} = O(\log^4{n})$?

Comment: Thereabouts, if you want to overkill it, $\ldots = d^{4}\log^{4}n \leq n^{8} \in O(n^{8})$, and we've contradicted the Space Hierarchy Theorem.

Comment: Aha! So you can conclude that $(\forall L \in PSPACE) L$ is decidable in $O(n^d)$ space and in $O(\log^4{n}) = o(n^d)$ space, and so no language exists that is decidable in $O(n^d)$ and not in $o(n^d)$, right?

Comment: Also, for the math part, why doesn't $|x|$ use $(\log^4{n})^{1/d}$ space, so that $|f(x)| = O(|x|^d) = O(((\log^4{n})^{1/d})^d) = O((\log^4{n}))$?

Comment: Part 1: So what you have is that if $TQBF \in SPACE(\log^{4}n)$ then $PSPACE \subseteq SPACE(n^{8})$, but by the Space Hierarchy Theorem we already know that $DSPACE(n^{k}) \subset PSPACE$ for all $k$, and hence our contradiction. ([Savitch's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitch's_theorem) takes care of any move between $NSPACE$ and $DSPACE$ implicit in the $SPACE$ part).

Comment: Part 2: If $|x| = n$, then $|f(x)| \leq n^{d}$, so we can solve $f(x)$ with $O((\log(|f(x)|))^{4})=O((\log(n^{d}))^{4})$ space. Ignoring the constant, $(\log(n^{d}))^{4} = (d\log n)^{4}$ and you got the rest.